# Get the URL inside within script tag html5player.setVideoUrlHigh

Tags: php, html5-video, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the `url` inside a  tag within script `html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('http://www.example.com/videourl_here.mp4')`

Currently using this script but is not working:

```
$url = 'http://www.siteurl.com/embedframe38295/';
$content= file_get_contents($url);
  preg_match_all('#html5player.setVideoUrlHigh\(\'.*'/')', $url, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
   $videoURL = ($matches[0][0]);
echo $videoURL;
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: What is the problem you re seeing - i.e. what is the error or incorrect output?